# Aws cloud formation template: how to provide retention period for Kinesis resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

Aws cloud formation template: how to provide retention period for Kinesis resource?

Hi, 
I want to specify retention period for Kinesis , I didn't find any property in documentation. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to do it through CF.
Kinesis stream is being created by CreateStream API call while changing retention period requires separate call, two of them actually: IncreaseStreamRetentionPeriod and DecreaseStreamRetentionPeriod. They can be called only after stream is created.

Comment: If you're building Infra as a Code, you can set it easily using terraform by HashiCorp https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_stream.html#retention_period

Answer (score 0):

```
MongoCDCStream:
Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
Properties:
  Name: !Ref CFNStreamName
  RetentionPeriodHours: !Ref CFNRetensionHours
  ShardCount: !Ref CFNShardCount
  StreamEncryption:
      EncryptionType: KMS
      KeyId: alias/aws/kinesis
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about data records that are stored in shards to remain accessible. then below is the property.

RetentionPeriodHours
The number of hours for the data records that are stored in shards to remain accessible. The default value is 24. For more information about the stream retention period, see Changing the Data Retention Period in the Amazon Kinesis Developer Guide.

Required: No

Type: Integer

Update requires: No interruption

```
MyStream:
  Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
  Properties:
    Name: MyKinesisStream
    RetentionPeriodHours: 168
    ShardCount: 3
    StreamEncryption:
        EncryptionType: KMS
        KeyId: !Ref myKey
    Tags:
      -
        Key: Environment
        Value: Production
```

Reference URL:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html